# How to make use of two RJ11 to transmit the internet

Tags: networking, rj-11

Here is my situation:

- There are two wall sockets in the house which have a RJ11 entry point. I am assuming that these two are connected since I used to have a telephone connected to each.
- One of the two RJ11 socket has a cable that goes into a RJ11 splitter, one goes into the phone, one goes into the ADSL modem

Is there a way for which I could pipe my internet connection to the second RJ11 socket?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: You could tie cat5 [or better] to one end of the phone cable & use it to pull the cat5 through … otherwise, no, it's zero use for networking.

Comment: That is a slippery slope question... Basically to get 10/100 Ethernet you need 2 pairs of wires, using pins 1,2,3, and 6 of a RJ45 jack (1000Mbps Ethernet requires all 8 wires). IF you have the proper connection from 1 point to the other (the wire can't be bridged/tapped anywhere, common in residential units), you MIGHT be able to rewire both ends the proper jacks and use it as an ethernet connection. I did this in my old apartment which had unrated 6-pair cable for wiring, and in short distances it worked. There is ZERO guarantee that it would work in your instance though

Comment: I second @acejavelin's comment. Theoretically, you can transmit bare ethernet via 4 wires, but this is _non-standard_ and you'd have to crimp the cables/adapters by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure. You can buy VDSL modems that can produce phenomenal speeds with this kind of wiring. Quite expensive though, ~130€ for an Allnet ALL-MC115VDSL2 for example. You’d need two.

The real problem is how these phone sockets are connected. Because in POTS you could get away with just wiring everything in parallel and it sort-of worked. For a VDSL connection (or any connection, really) to work, you need a dedicated line that is not connected to anything else on either end.

Since you say you have an ADSL splitter + modem connected to one socket, this socket is... well, in use. Only if you could install a new one next to it that has a 1:1 connection to the other one could any of this ever work.